# What is the correct way to add a string to SQL Server field of type char[x]?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, types, sql-server-2000, powershell-3.0

I am writing a script in PowerShell to utilize a stored procedure in my SQL Server 2000 database. To utilize the stored procedure w/ params I use the `AddWithValue()` method for `sqlcmd.Parameters`. I am attempting to insert a string into a column with data type `char` of size 8. I have been playing around with the `AddWithValue()` method, but I keep getting one of the two following errors:

> Cannot convert value "aamstest" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long."
>   At D:\scripts\SCADAViewBulkAdd\scadaview_bulk_add.ps1:196 char:2
>   +     $SqlCmd.Paramters.AddWithValue("@USNAME",[char]$USNAME);
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocation
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   At D:\scripts\SCADAViewBulkAdd\scadaview_bulk_add.ps1:197 char:2
>   +     $SqlCmd.Paramters.AddWithValue("@GRNAME",$GRNAME);
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddUserToGroup 
    @USNAME char(8), @GRNAME char(8) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO GLOBE_USER_GROUP 
    VALUES (@USNAME, @GRNAME)
END
GO
```

`AddWithValue()` called from here:

```
# Call SQL Stored Procedure spAddUserToGroup
function SpAddUserToGroup ($usnameParam,$grnameParam)
{
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.DATA.SqlClient.SqlConnection;

    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER=server01;DATABASE=FIGDB;UID=y;PWD=y";

    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;

    # Indicate working with stored procedure
    $SqlCmd.CommandType=[System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure';

    # Supply name of stored procedure
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = "spAddUserToGroup";
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;

    # Set stored procedure parameters
    $USNAME = $usnameParam;
    $GRNAME = $grnameParam;

    Write-Host $USNAME
    Write-Host $GRNAME

    # Add parameters to string
    $SqlCmd.Paramters.AddWithValue("@USNAME",[char]$USNAME);
    $SqlCmd.Paramters.AddWithValue("@GRNAME",$GRNAME);

    # Initialize SQL Adapter
    #$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlAdapter;
    #$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd;

    ...
}
```

**Question:** how can I utilize the stored procedure to insert a string into a column of type `char[8]` with PowerShell? Are my errors a result of calling `AddWithValue()` incorrectly or am I handling my variable types poorly?

Comment: When casting my string to char array using `ToCharArray()` I receive the "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" where I am utilizing the `AddWithValue` method. However, I am certain that the two variables are not `null` as I am printing them after the cast and before the `AddValueWith()` method. I am not sure as to why the variables are being read as `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer

Turns out you can specify the parameter names, but you don't have to.  I think your actual issue here is that you've spelled Parameter wrong, which is why SQL Isn't accepting your input.

Change your code to this, and it should work.

```
$SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USNAME",[char]$USNAME);
$SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GRNAME",$GRNAME);
```

## Old Answer, Wrong

*I don't think you are supposed to specify the parameter name when you call a stored procedure.  Try this instead:*

Change these two lines:

```
$SqlCmd.Paramters.AddWithValue("@USNAME",[char]$USNAME);
$SqlCmd.Paramters.AddWithValue("@GRNAME",$GRNAME);
```

To this:

```
$SqlCmd.Paramters.AddWithValue([char]$USNAME,$GRNAME)
```

*Also, PowerShell doesn't require line ending characters, like a semicolon.*

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply, but that doesn't seem to work for me. Whenever I cast using `ToCharArray()` or `char[[]]` I get the "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error on the `AddWithValue()` calls. Looking at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) it states that the first paramter should be of type string indicating the name of the parameter. Would it be different for PowerShell?

Comment: I found the error!  It looks like you have a typo in Parameter.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. The better half of the morning lost to a missing character, but it is working now. Thanks for all the help good sir.